# influxdb group by from most recent time

Tags: influxdb

Using "group by" to bin 5m intervals. The way it works now it will group from 15min to just under 20min and this will be give a 15 timestamp.

Is it possible to group from 20 to just above 15 and give it a 20 min timestamp.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no: the time would always be the beginning of each time group.

I mean, you can group like that with `ORDER BY time DESC` - for some functions (like `DIFFERENCE()`) that does matter - but the timestamp still be the beginning.

That seems to be a feature of InfluxDB (although I haven't found mention of that in InfluxDB docs).

PS In Kapacitor, [you can use the time of the selected point](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.4/nodes/influx_q_l_node/#usepointtimes) instead of the time group interval beginning - but only for selector functions, not aggregates